# What thread does the MediaPlayer OnPreparedListener run on?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Reading the source code for `VideoView`, I see that there are several variables that are seemingly accessed from multiple threads but are not marked as volatile. `mCurrentState`, for example, seems to be accessed in several listeners as well as the calling thread. Out of curiosity, why are these variables not marked volatile? For example, if I call `start` while the `onPreparedListener` is running, could `mCurrentState` have race condition problems?